# for loop with lists R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, assign

I want to create two lists of data frames in a for loop, but I cannot use assign:

```
dat <- data.frame(name = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 13)),
                  x = c(1,3,4,4,5,3,7,6,5,7,8,6,4,3,9,1,2,3,5,4,6,3,1),
                  y = c(1.1,3.2,4.3,4.1,5.5,3.7,7.2,6.2,5.9,7.3,8.6,6.3,4.2,3.6,9.7,1.1,2.3,3.2,5.7,4.8,6.5,3.3,1.2))

a <- dat[dat$name == "a",]
b <- dat[dat$name == "b",]

samp <- vector(mode = "list", length = 100)
h <- list(a,b)
hname <- c("a", "b")

for (j in 1:length(h)) {
  for (i in 1:100) {
    samp[[i]] <- sample(1:nrow(h[[j]]), nrow(h[[j]])*0.5)
    assign(paste("samp", hname[j], sep="_"), samp[[i]])
  }
}
```

Instead of lists named `samp_a` and `samp_b` I get vectors which contain the result of the 100th sample. I want to get a list `samp_a` and `samp_b`, which have all the different samples for `dat[dat$name == a,]` and `dat[dat$name == a,]`.

How could I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? You're almost (possibly always) better off keeping your workspace structured, there's no point in creating 100 numbered objects.

Comment: Because I need 100 randomly drawn samples to test them with certain functions. This loop is within a function, so my workspace will be structured, I guess...

Comment: you have them in your `samp` list, why do you need to assign them to different objects in the workspace ? Wether you want to feed them to different models, or save them to different files, or loop through them with lapply or for loops, all of this can be done by keeping them in a list

Comment: For me it is more complicated to see, what the code means, when I put the two lists in one list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating two different lists and avoiding using assign:

```
Option 1:

# create empty list
samp_a <-list()
samp_b <- list()

for (j in seq(h)) {

    # fill samp_a list
    if(j == 1){
        for (i in 1:100) {
            samp_a[[i]] <- sample(1:nrow(h[[j]]), nrow(h[[j]])*0.5)
        }
      # fill samp_b list
    } else if(j == 2){
        for (i in 1:100) {
            samp_b[[i]] <- sample(1:nrow(h[[j]]), nrow(h[[j]])*0.5)
        }
    }
}
```

You could use assign too, shorter answer:

```
Option 2:

for (j in seq(hname)) {
    l = list()
    for (i in 1:100) {
        l[[i]] <- sample(1:nrow(h[[j]]), nrow(h[[j]])*0.5)
    }
    assign(paste0('samp_', hname[j]), l)
    rm(l)
}
```

Comment: The OP's `for-loop` may not be correct for what they want, but correct me if I'm wrong. All this loop does is take 100 samples of 5 (or 6) numbers from 1:10 (or 1:13). OP wants a sample of paired `x,y` for `a` and `b`. You need to change the `sample` call to `samp_a[[i]] <- h[[j]][sample(1:nrow(h[[j]]), nrow(h[[j]])*0.5), ]`. Unless OP wants a random `x` paired with a random `y`.

Comment: @Anonymouscoward may be you are right, let OP confirm.

Comment: @YOLO I think the code is correct. It takes 100 samples for each name and assigns them to the lists samp_a and samp_b. It actually assigns the indices of the rows, so if I apply the indices to my data frame, the samples are drawn. Or am I missing something?

Comment: no, you are right, since you want the indices, it's correct

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use an `lapply` for this using the `rep` function. Unless you want a random `x`, paired with a random `y`. This will maintain the existing paired order.

```
dat <- data.frame(name = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 13)),
              x = c(1,3,4,4,5,3,7,6,5,7,8,6,4,3,9,1,2,3,5,4,6,3,1),
              y = c(1.1,3.2,4.3,4.1,5.5,3.7,7.2,6.2,5.9,7.3,8.6,6.3,4.2,3.6,9.7,1.1,2.3,3.2,5.7,4.8,6.5,3.3,1.2))

a <- dat[dat$name == "a",]
b <- dat[dat$name == "b",]

h <- list(a,b)
hname <- c("a", "b")

testfunc <- function(df) {
#df[sample(nrow(df), nrow(df)*0.5), ] #gives you the values in your data frame
sample(nrow(df), nrow(df)*0.5) # just gives you the indices
}

lapply(h, testfunc) # This gives you the standard lapply format, and only gives one a, and one b
samp <- lapply(rep(h, 100), testfunc) # This shows you how to replicate the function n times, giving you 100 a and 100 b data.frames in a list

samp_a <- samp[c(TRUE, FALSE)] # Applies a repeating T/F vector, selecting the odd data.frames, which in this case are the `a` frames.
samp_b <- samp[c(FALSE, TRUE)] # And here, the even data.frames, which are the `b` frames.
```